# Passing value along with form in POST data in Django

Tags: python, django

When I render the form in HTML, I use this view. the patient_id is used to denote what patient the check in is for and for name display and such.

```
def Checkin(request, patient_id):
    patient = get_object_or_404(PatientInfo, pk=patient_id)
    form = forms.PatientCheckinForm()
    return render(request, 'patientRecords/checkin.html', {'patient': patient, 'form':form})
```

When I submit the patient form filled out as a POST method, I still need access to the patient_id. Currently this is the view that accepts the filled form:

```
def CheckinSubmit(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.PatientCheckinForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.date_time_of_checkin = dt.now()
        instance.patient = patient.patient_id
        instance.save()
        return redirect('patientRecords/index.html')
```

I want to set the instance.patient to the patient_id that was part of patient from the Checkin view. Is there a way to pass the patient data back along with the POST method or is there another way this can be done?

For reference, here is my template and I am using ModelForm not form.

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <h1>Patient Checkin</h1>
  <h2>{{patient.first_name}} {{patient.last_name}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <form  action="{% url 'patientRecords:checkinsubmit' %}" method="POST" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to simply add a hidden input to your form to capture the patient ID:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <h1>Patient Checkin</h1>
  <h2>{{patient.first_name}} {{patient.last_name}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <form  action="{% url 'patientRecords:checkinsubmit' %}" method="POST" class="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="{{patient.patient_id}}" />
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

(Note this assumes that the patient ID is accessible from the `patient_id` property of the `patient` object.)

Then, in your `CheckinSubmit` method, you can access this value via `request.POST.get('patient_id')`

Alternatively, it appears that your check in form loads with the patient ID in the URL. In your `CheckinSubmit` method, you should be able to access this URL through the `request.META.HTTP_REFERER` property. You could then parse the URL (e.g., using `request.META.HTTP_REFERER.split('/')[len(request.META.HTTP_REFERER.split('/')) - 1]` to pull out the patient ID.

Comment: Getting closer! different error now. I'm getting "ValueError: Cannot assign "'15'": "CheckIn.patient_id" must be a "PatientInfo" instance" error. 'PatientInfo' is the name of a different model than the one I am currently trying to save to. the 15 is going into a 'checkin' model as a foreign key to 'PatientInfo'.

Comment: Judging by the error, the `patient` property is expecting an object (of type `PatientInfo`), not an integer/ID. Therefore, in your `CheckinSubmit` method, you'll need to pull that object from the DB using the ID to look it up, then assign that to `instance.patient`. For example, assuming you're importing your app models into your views file, you might pull it in, and assign it to `instance.patient`, like so: `instance.patient = models.PatientInfo.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('patient_id'))`

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
<form method="post" action = "{% url 'user_search_from_group' %}"> 
      <div class="module-option clearfix">
           <div class="input-append pull-left">
                <input type="hidden" name="groupname" value="{{ gpname }}" />
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Filter by name" id="username3" name="username3" required>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">
                         <i class="icon-search"></i>
                 </button>
           </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Here a hidden field is used to pass a value along form.

```
def user_search_from_group(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username3 = request.POST.get('username3')
        gname = request.POST.get('groupname')
```

Using request we are use the value inside view