# Auto display the form's data in other view (django)

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using django forms to get some data from the user.
It works well with the DB.

How can I display that data (in a different page) right after submitting?

The flow should be:

1. The user fills the form
2. Clicks submit (creates an object and saves to DB)
3. The user is redirected to another page in which the data he just submitted is presented.

Basically I need to pass the object's PK (the one the user just created) from one view to another.

It's supposed to be fairly simple yet I couldn't find a decent solution for that issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the point where you save the object to the database. You have the instance of the objects, let's say you have something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    my_object  = form.save() #This or whichever way you use to get the object.

    #You can redirect directly
    return redirect('presenting-data',my_object.id)
```

Where presenting data is the name of the url and view that you use to present data.

Comment: Is it giving you an error that you can show us?

Comment: Thanks! I've done that but I'm still having trouble:
`if f.is_valid():`
`obj = f.save()`
`return redirect('data-page', obj.id)`

`def data_page(request, num):`
`return render (request, 'data-page.html', {'pk': num})``

(Not even trying to display the form yet, just to making sure the `num` variable is passed correctly)

I get 'Reverse for 'data-page' with arguments '(17,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried ['data-page/$']'
(17 = the current num)

It's as if the id is being passed as a string. What am I missing?

Comment: How is your url configured? It's seems that in you url definition, you have missed the parameter

Comment: You're right. If I pass the pk through the url it works. Thanks 
Just out of curiosity, is it possible to pass it otherwise (meaning not through the visible url?)

Comment: You can pass anything that you want inside a form using POST instead of GET, that way, the url shows nothing. Check this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482742/passing-value-along-with-form-in-post-data-in-django

Comment: Yea but they talk about passing an existing object through a form - I want the form to create the object and then pass it using POST (we managed to do that through the URL using GET).

Comment: You can store the pk in the request.session after creating the object and then retrieve it where you need it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/